# Is there some sort of function transformation expressing $(X\implies Y)\Leftrightarrow (\neg X\lor Y)$?

Tags: propositional-calculus, type-theory

Is there a functional interpretation if the replacement for for the [material implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_%28rule_of_inference%29)?:

$$(X\implies Y)\Leftrightarrow (\neg X\lor Y)$$

Given a function from type $X$ to type $Y$, viewed as a witness of the proposition $X\implies Y$, can I obtain a proof for $\neg X\lor Y$? The connective "$\lor$" gets translated to a pair - I fail to see how this relates to a function/process, something which doesn't even require a proof of $X$.

Comment: I would say the "or" should give a member of a disjoint union. Since there is no way to know which part of the disjoint union to aim for, the equivalence in not constructively valid and you cannot expect to get this direction. The other direction should pose no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find the post, but Neighborhood of Infinity's [Exceptions, Disjunctions, and Continuations](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/02/exceptions-disjunctions-and.html) describes this topic. I haven't fully understood everything presented there, but the author asks about the isomorhism between $a \to b$ and $\lnot a \lor b$, what the type $\lnot a$ means ($a \to \bot$), and what $\lnot\lnot a$ means ($(a \to \bot) \to \bot$), and so on.  I'm not sure whether it will answer your question or not, but it might prove a useful starting point for you, or some other answer-ers.